# Asus Zephyrus M Ubuntu bootable?

Tags: boot

Currently i have saved up enough money for a new laptop, since im going to use this laptop mainly for programming, pentesting and such i need good power and found this is a laptop that both has power and looks nice, ive been using a Toshiba Satallite for almost 5 years now and have used it with ubuntu, my question is if its possible to change the os from windows to ubuntu 18.04 on the Asus Zephyrus M

Comment: I have ASUS GU501 which mainly the same as Zephyrus M GM501. Here are the things that I still can't get working: Trackpad (can't even detect it), NVIDIA.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change your OS. You can dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10. My current configuration is a Zephyrus M that hasn Ubuntu 18.04 running installed with NVIDIA drivers.